# Should Vuex store be used for GetById requests?

Tags: vuex

I have Vue app using Vuex for many of its api/axios calls, with the front end accessing that data via the store.

I have Show vie akin to ProductDetails, where I need pull one record out of the database to display its attributes.

I had been doing this basically from component->services->axios. however I noticed in the documentation these calls made from vuex instead.

eg from here: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html

they show the store as:

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    todos: [
      { id: 1, text: '...', done: true },
      { id: 2, text: '...', done: false }
    ]
  }
getters: {
  // ...
  getTodoById: (state) => (id) => {
    return state.todos.find(todo => todo.id === id)
  }
}
})
```

Obviously, when there are only two records, this is immaterial, but is this the correct way to structure this in production?

Comment: It's certainly not an incorrect way.  This is nothing more than storing some stuff in state and accessing it later by id.  Nothing wrong with that.  But if you have no need to store items in Vuex, then this wouldn't affect you.  One benefit to storing results, aside from sharing among components, is being able to quickly access data a second time without making repetitive calls to an api.  It also gives you the option to download all of your app's data during a loading process and access it later.

Comment: @Dan, I guess my concern was performance, loading entire tables into store to filter them later, vs having routes that deliver the specific data I need at the time. If you get to having multiple tables and millions of records, it starts to feel expensive

Comment: You won't find any serious apps loading millions of records.  In the example you linked, there are some todo items; how many of those might there be a need to load simultaneously into an app?  Dozens, maybe.  Thousands, max?  If you consider what is a reasonable amount of data to load, then it will make more sense why to load data into Vuex.

Comment: Here is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61205211/2185093) I posted recently about a similar topic.  I'm sure there are better ones out there but this at least covers the basics.